# How to convert the epoch time present in the entire column to a human time with HiveQL?

Tags: hive, impala, hue

I want to know how to convert a column containing epoch times into human times.

for example look at this table. here the time is in epoch format

| job | time |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1877325549 |
| b | 1888957747 |
| c | 1889962545 |
| d | 1866489715 |
| e | 1885478662 |

now i want to convert it to the following format

| job | time |
| --- | --- |
| a | 28/06/2028 12:49:09 |
| b | 10/11/2029 03:59:07 |
| c | 21/11/2029 19:05:45 |
| d | 23/02/2029 02:51:55 |
| e | 30/07/2029 21:34:22 |

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: And also, please don't add `.............` in the end of every question you post.

Answer (score 0):

use `from_unixtime(BIGINT)`. Example -

```
select from_unixtime(1877325549)
```

As you know epoch is seconds between 1-jan-1970 and the date. `from_unixtime()` calculates date based on that.

[image]

Comment: i have to convert te whole column in one query

Comment: can you pls use `select job, from_unixtime(time) time from mytable;` ?

Comment: Youre right. It seems not an epoch seconds. Could you please give some more info on the column? How this is generated ? Here is online tool to convert - https://www.epochconverter.com/